# Codeigniter load custom upload config

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a small problem. I have a custom configuration file for uploading. I want to load the settings without redefining them.

Okay, my configuration look like this:

**config.php**

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'tmp/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
$config['file_name'] = '';
$config['max_size'] = '';
$config['encrypt_name'] = false;
$config['remove_spaces'] = true;
```

**Controller**

```
// Here is my problem $config[]
// How to load settings from config.php without again defining $config array

$config['upload_path'] =   $this->config->item('upload_path');
$config['allowed_types'] = $this->config->item('allowed_types');
$config['file_name'] =     $this->config->item('file_name');
$config['max_size'] =      $this->config->item('max_size');
$config['encrypt_name'] =  $this->config->item('encrypt_name');
$config['remove_spaces'] = $this->config->item('remove_spaces');  

$this->load->library('upload',$config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
    redirect('extension/');
}
```

I want to bypass the redefinition of $config['test] = $this->config->item('test');

Is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am missing something, but simply do not put the lines in your controller. This will effectively not redeclare it?

Comment: And how to load declaration from config in $this->load->library('upload', WHAT NOW HERE );

Comment: You simply call the config file upload.php and put it in your config folder. The upload class will automatically load the config items declared in this custom file. No need to initialize it. See here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html, search for "Setting preferences in a config file"

Comment: Yeah but in Setting preferences he define $config array in one file. But my configuration data is stored in other file /config/upload.php i try what u say and dont work

Comment: If he defined the upload settings in the main config.php file, it will not have any effect, unless he uses `$this->config->item('whatever_item')`. If you remove those calls to `$this->config->item('whatever_item');` it will use the file upload.php you put in your application/config directory. If this does not work, ensure that you use the correct format for the upload file. Opens with `<?php` tag, and then declare the variables, make sure there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html describes how to load custom config items. I would recommend creating a custom config file as the CI website suggests and just loading that custom config file where you want.

So you'd have something like `$this->config->load('custom_upload_settings', FALSE, TRUE);` and in that file you'd have the settings you'd want to override.

// Loads a config file named custom_upload_settings.php and assigns it to an index named "blog_settings"
`$this->config->load('custom_upload_settings', TRUE);`

// Retrieve a config item named site_name contained within the custom_upload_settings array
`$site_name = $this->config->item('site_name', 'custom_upload_settings');`

Comment: Man i have that in my constuctor i dont put all code bcs is to big.   // Load config
$this->load->config('extension', FALSE, TRUE);

Comment: I don't know what you mean? `$this->config->load('custom_upload_settings', FALSE, TRUE);` would be loading a new file that you need to create (so it should be empty until you add the `set_item()` lines).

Comment: Yeah u dont know what i mean. My problem is not in config and loading config... My problem is upload library how to catch settings from my custom config without again defining that.

Comment: Did you read the guide I posted, it describes that functionality. I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

YES, Codeigniter support customize upload config.
You can set config/upload.php initial settings.

Another controller;

```php
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'assets/uploads/articles'; // change custom config
$this->upload->initialize($config, FALSE);
```

Most important initialize second parameter is **FALSE**. This parameter is related to RESET.
while keeping default upload settings, you can change other settings.

More information;
[Codeigniter File Upload Initialize](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::initialize)